# How to validate name using REGEXP

Tags: php

I am trying to validate my name's text box so even if they by pass it it won't still accept the name with spcial characters like "!@#$%^&*()_" and numbers too and this is my code:

```
  public function updateuserAction(){
    $this->view->disable();
    $get = $this->request;
    $key = $get->get('key');
    $email = $get->get('email');
    $password = $get->get('password');
    $realName = $get->get('realName');
    $type = $get->get('userType');

        if(filter_var($realname, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp" => "/^[a-zA-Z]+$/")))){
        $url = $this->apiUrl."user/update?q=(key:$key,email:".urlencode($email).",password:".urlencode($password).",realName:".urlencode($realName).",userType:".urlencode($type).")&envelope=false";
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $this->curlopt);
        echo  curl_exec($ch);
        }else {
        echo "Failed";
        }

}
```

this is my code i don't know how to insert validation here. it always give me an error message whenever i add validation code here. I am a newbie in this line so if could help it would mean alot to e. thanks!

I already added my trial code

Comment: Please show your attempted validation code. We can't tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't.

Comment: You should never validate names. Ever.

Comment: i'm just doing this so users couldn't add special characters

Comment: @Barmar : i already put the code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aww man, now i know what's making my code always fall on failed -*- just because of $realname to $realName -*- i forgot it's case sensitive. thanks for your efforts to answer guys :D

Answer (score 0):

The php regular expression matching function is - [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php;).

Your question is a bit vague but from what I can gather you want to validate that the username contains only alphabet characters.  As such try something like

```
if (preg_match("^[a-zA-Z]+$") == false)
{
   echo "Username is invalid.";
   die(); // or some other error handling code
}
```